# Use Aliases In Calculations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

In SQL Server 2008 I am attempting to run the below calculation, but I am getting an error of

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Invalid column name 'Rpt1'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Invalid column name 'Rpt2'.

This is the syntax I am trying to execute.

> Declare @saleID varchar(100), @totalsales int

```
Set @totalsales = (Select COUNT(numsales) 
                  FROM OPENQUERY(444.222.333.123, 'Select 
                                                   numsales, saleID 
                                                   FROM saledate')
                  WHERE saleID = @saleID)

Select
Rpt1 = count(case when empID = '1931' Then 1 else 0 end)
,Rpt2 = count(case when empID = '1831' Then 1 else 0 end)
,Balance = @totalsales-Rpt1-Rpt2
From totalsaleinfo
Where saleid = @saleid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store the rpt1 and rpt2 as variables then subtrack from total, not as the aliases.

Or perform:

```
Select
@totalsales-
(count(case when empID = '1931' Then 1 else 0 end))
-
(count(case when empID = '1831' Then 1 else 0 end))
as Balance
From totalsaleinfo
```

Where saleid = @saleid

Comment: The `count(case when ... then 1 else 0 end)` won't give what they expect. Use either `sum(case when ... then 1 else 0 end)` or `count(case when ... then 1 else null end)`

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is you can layer your queries as sub-queries, which allow you to capture all results, like so.  Also you most likely wanted to use "sum" instead of "count".

```
select Rpt1, Rpt2, Balance = @totalsales-Rpt1-Rpt2
FROM   (Select Rpt1 = sum(case when empID = '1931' Then 1 else 0 end)
        ,      Rpt2 = sum(case when empID = '1831' Then 1 else 0 end)
        From totalsaleinfo
        Where saleid = @saleid) AS sums
```